# Yii2. How to get access to the subquery field in a search model?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a search model:

```
$query = User::find();
$myOrdersQuery = Request::find()
                            ->select('count(*)')
                            ->where([
                                'user_id' => $clientsIds,
                                'agent_id' => $this->viewer->id,
                            ]);
$query->addSelect(['my_orders_count' => $myOrdersQuery]);
```

When I'm trying to print it into the GridView

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'my_orders_count',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->my_orders_count;
            }
        ],
```

it says Getting unknown property: common\models\User::my_orders_count

Please help to get access to this field

Answer (score 2):

You can do like for  calculated field

ad a public var in User model

```
public user_count;
```

use alias in select

```
.....
$myOrdersQuery = Request::find()
                        ->select('count(*) as user_count')
                        ->where([
                       ....
```

then simply refer to the public field name in gridview

```
   [
        'attribute' => 'user_count',

    ],
```